# Regex grouping selection

Tags: regex, grouping, selection

I'm trying to work with Regex and grouping and I'm having trouble retrieving some information. What I want to achieve is, having the following text:

```
<ed><a0><bd><ed><b2><9c><ed><a0><bd><ed><b2><9c><ed><a0><bd><ed><b4><91><ed><a0><bd><ed><b4><91>
```

I want a regex expression that selects groups of characters, taking in account the odds `<ed>`

So for example, the first group selected would be `<ed><a0><bd><ed><b2><9c>` and the second group selected would be `<ed><a0><bd><ed><b2><9c>`

In which way can I achieve this?

Comment: `In which way can I achieve this?` - Learn regex. Heres your answer: `(<.*?9c>)` https://regex101.com/r/oD8oR0/1

Comment: Your answer won't work...

Comment: As Rafael said, it does not work. I found the solution by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the way to do it. To be clear is a way to extract emojis from twitter text obtained via the twitteR API in R, so the code would be

```
str_extract_all(i, pattern='<U\\+....>|<ed>.*?<ed>.*?>.*?>')
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use the Python implementation of Regex, this will work:

```
re.findall('<ed>.*?<ed>.*?(?=<ed>)', string)
```